# Binary files are corrupted after upload to Google Drive (0x0A turns to 0x0D 0x0A)

Tags: google-drive-api

Seems it is a fresh issue. I didn't have this issue before (at least 1-2 weeks ago), my code wasn't changed. So I think the issue happens on Google side.

After I upload any binary file using Drive API I get corrupted files. Google turns every 0X0A symbol into 0x0D 0x0A sequence.

The code worked perfectly before. I tried with large files, small files. Every time I get corruption.

However if I upload using Drive UI I don't get the corruption problem.

Comment: Can you post how do you initiate your resumable session.
And especially how do you set you upload content length?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with simple upload also. The code is simple. Just one PUT HTTP request to $uploadUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/$fileId" with $contentType = 'image/jpg' and $body=file_get_contents('M:/Temp/sample.jpg').

Comment: Content length is the exact file size of the uploaded file.

Comment: google-api-php-client with CURL are used to execute HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was turned on CURL option CURLOPT_CRLF.